# react-admin expand Unknown dataProvider function: getOne

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm trying to create expand option with react-admin.

In my `AdminPanel.js`:

```
class AdminPanel extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Admin dataProvider={myDataProvider}>
                    ...
                    <Resource title="Submission" name="submission" list={SubmissionList} />
                    ...
                </Admin>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const SubmissionList = (props) => (
    <List {...props} pagination={<PostPagination />}>
        <Datagrid expand={<ContentShow/>}>
               ...
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
const ContentShow = props => (
    <Show
        {...props}
        title=" "
    >
        <SimpleShowLayout>
            <RichTextField source="content" />
        </SimpleShowLayout>
    </Show>
);
```

The problem is when I try to expand the entry, it gives me error saying *Unknown dataProvider function: getOne*.

*How can I resolve this?*

*It will be better not to use dataProvider any more*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple I console.log props and found the error.

Here is my solution :

```
const ContentShow = props => (
    <SimpleShowLayout>
        <RichTextField source={props.record.content}/>
    </SimpleShowLayout>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `SimpleShowLayout` directly without `Show`

```
const ContentShow = props => (
    <SimpleShowLayout>
        <RichTextField source="content" />
    </SimpleShowLayout>
);
```

The reason for the error:

Is `ContentShow` passed to `Resource` component as `show` props? If not, `ContentShow` component doesn't have `actions` props. So it can't find the function `getOne`. (ref: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/53aac9b84760cf56fa3d5bf5a05cea48245e3c92/packages/ra-core/src/controller/useShowController.ts#L57)

Correct usage of the expand props:

You should pass a presentation component that depends on record props(`content` object in this case).

Comment: it just displays "content" string, not what "content" contains  : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7cfN.png ...